# I'm having trouble exporting touchdevelop apps to cordova

Tags: cordova, export, touchdevelop

starting shell watch...
starting with , pid: 23188
start, autoupdate=false
Deployment key: 02c46ba6aa3967852084c6d0860fd59c8581afc9
Editor URL: http://localhost:4242/editor/beta#td_deployment_key=02c46ba6aa396785
2084c6d0860fd59c8581afc9
running: >start http://localhost:4242/editor/beta#td_deployment_key=02c46ba6aa39
67852084c6d0860fd59c8581afc9
exception (top): Error: write EPIPE
Error: write EPIPE
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:746:11)
    at Socket._writeGeneric (net.js:690:26)
    at Socket._write (net.js:709:8)
    at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:301:12)
    at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:288:5)
    at Socket.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:217:11)
    at Socket.write (net.js:634:40)
    at runCommand (C:\Users\ValuedAcerCustomer\Desktop\New folder\tdserver.js:65
1:16)
    at openUrl (C:\Users\ValuedAcerCustomer\Desktop\New folder\tdserver.js:1899:
9)
    at startUp (C:\Users\ValuedAcerCustomer\Desktop\New folder\tdserver.js:2273:
13)
exception (top): Error: spawn cmd ENOENT
Error: spawn cmd ENOENT
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:746:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1053:32)
    at child_process.js:1144:20
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:11)

this was what happened when I tried to run touchdevelop locally from my folder. I also received a Windows Host Script error, saying that in line 1 and char 1, there is an invalid character. This line of code:#!/usr/bin/env node
was the one that resulted in the Microsoft JScript compilation error. Please help me!!